# How is Easter celebrated in Hungary?

Tags: hungary

I'll be traveling in Hungary (from Austria towards Budapest) over Easter.  What should I expect?

For example, in Germany it is traditional to have huge [bonfires](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osterfeuer) on the Saturday before Easter.  Is there anything similar in Hungary?

Answer (score 8):

There are not too many openly celebrated Easter festivals in Hungary. There is a [quite touristy festival](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holl%C3%B3k%C5%91) in Hollókő where they replicate how Easter was celebrated 100 years ago. Similar events take place at the [open air museum](http://www.urlaub-ungarn.at/kultur/ostern-in-ungarn/osterereignisse-2013.html) in Szentendre. Those mainly consist out of wearing traditional clothes, a water-pouring ritual and painting & gifting of eggs.

While there are some very traditional and very diverse local, and more detailed traditions in terms of what food is served for Easter and which pattern the eggs are painted, I am afraid that you will not find anything like the bonfires in Germany.